# How can I use different proguard files in different flavors or for different build types?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, obfuscation, android-productflavors

I need to make different flavors for test libraries. Why? Well, I want project to be fully secured so I wanna minifying to be enabled all the time(even for debug build type).

While making tests I'm using different classes from project, 
so I decided to change proguard files using flavor. It looks like something this :

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            testProguardFile 'test-proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            testProguardFile 'test-proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ...
    productFlavors{
        forTest{
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules1.pro', 'debug-rules.pro'
        }
        forRelease{
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'debug-rules.pro'
        }
   }
}
```

And proguard-rules* files

proguard-rules:

```
-dontwarn blablabla.**
-dontwarn blabla.**
-keep class bla.** { *; }
```

proguard-rules1:

```
-dontshrink
-dontobfuscate
-dontwarn
```

But this wasn't helpful for me. I want to run tests without obfuscation. Flavors doesn't have such param as minifyEnabled so I try to find any solution. So any suggestions about resolving an issue? May be someone had the same problem and find another solution (not using flavors) ?

Answer (score 16):

After a whole day messing with this I found the following works:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    flavorA {
        applicationIdSuffix ".a"
        proguardFile 'flavorA_rules.pro'
    }
    flavorB {
        applicationIdSuffix ".b"
    }

}
```

More info: [Include additional configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#add-configuration)

Comment: So `flavorA_rules.pro` replace `proguard-rules.pro` on `flavorA `?

Comment: @Cool Yes, you can verify later in `good-trainer-android/<module>/build/intermediates/aapt_proguard_file/<flavor name>` the generated proguard file

Comment: @TooCool Actually, as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#add-configuration) states, there won't be any replacements. The flavor now uses all three provided ProGuard rules.