# Add different proguard file for debug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build-type

I have a project with two modules. It exists a default configuration of build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

And I want to add a different configuration (proguard and minifying) for debug compilation as follow:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
        }
    }
```

When I put this code in my project, it doesn't compile. The log show a message error for each reference to another module:

```
Error:(37, 42) error: package com.example does not exist
```

Full Gradle configuration of the two modules.

The app module:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        ...
    }
}

repositories{
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

The library module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

Comment: You may check this link. It might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657886/how-can-i-use-different-proguard-files-in-different-flavors-or-for-different-bui

Answer (score 2):

I would try the following:

```
buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            }
            debug {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
            }
        }
```

Alternatively did you try putting the rules files into the build-types folders? You could put the `proguard-rules.pro` file into the build-types/release folder and the `proguard-rules-debug.pro` file into the build-types/debug folder.

Comment: proguard wont apply if you set `minifyEnabled false`